# Calculting the infimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the maps $u, \phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R^n}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be some class of functions and consider the quantity
$$\inf_{u \in \mathcal{F}} \left( \frac{|u|^2}{2}+u\cdot\phi\right) .$$
Assuming that $-\phi \in \mathcal{F}$, I guess the infimum will be attained at $u=-\phi$ as this is a parabola. Is this observation correct and can something be said if we consider
$$\inf_{u \in \mathcal{F}} \left( \frac{|u|^{2n}}{2n}+u\cdot\phi\right) $$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your first question in the positive, by proving that $-\phi$ is indeed the minimizer under the assumption that $-\phi\in\mathcal{F}$.

Consider the functional $\mathscr{J}:\mathcal{F}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$\mathscr{J}[u]=\frac{\lVert u\rVert^2}{2}+\langle u,\phi\rangle.$$

We know that

$$\mathscr{J}[-\phi]=\frac{\lVert\phi\rVert^2}{2}-\lVert\phi\rVert^2=-\frac{\lVert\phi\rVert^2}{2}.$$

Consider now some $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $-\phi+h\in\mathcal{F}$. Then

$$\mathscr{J}[-\phi+h]-\mathscr{J}[-\phi]=\frac{\lVert -\phi+h\rVert^2}{2}+\langle -\phi+h,\phi\rangle+\frac{\lVert\phi\rVert^2}{2}=\frac{\lVert\phi\rVert^2+\lVert h\rVert^2-2\langle\phi,h\rangle}{2}+\langle h,\phi\rangle-\frac{\lVert\phi\rVert^2}{2}=\frac{\lVert h\rVert^2}{2}\geq0.$$

From this it follows that

$$\mathscr{J}[-\phi]=\min_{u\in\mathcal{F}}\mathscr{J}[u].$$

Comment: Thank you, do you think if  this result can be generalised to $\inf_{u\in\mathcal{F}}(L(u)+u\cdot \phi)$ for some nonlinear $L$ with some properties?

Comment: @Alex I wouldn't count on it, since a big reason behind it working here is the relationship between the inner product and the norm induced by it. So of it did generalize lile that, I imagine the conditions on $L$ would have to be quite demanding